# Can we do routing using angular JS if we have same url for all the methods in the api?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I would like to know if I can perform routing operation in angular JS when I have same url for all the methods in the api.

**To be more specific about the question:**

I have a api which has same url for all the POST methods. The only thing that changes is the post data which I would send. So, my question is that, I want to pull some data by performing post request to the Api which I can do using Single Page Application using angular JS also. But, Is it possible to do this task using routing in angular js, The reason I'm thinking is because of the url, which does not change for any post methods? Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Regards,
Sandeep

Comment: That is a terrible design idea, but routing doesn't care, at all, about your backend API. It doesn't need it, doesn't use it, doesn't care about it. So the answer is yes.

Comment: Oh, Is it, Okay! Thank you for getting back to me. I just want to clarify whether, Using Routing is terrible idea or using SPA is terrible idea.

Comment: None of that. Using a single URL for all the methods in the API is a terrible idea. Would you find it a good idea is everything you do in JavaScript was sone by calling the same function, that would decide what to do based on the argument passed to the function?

Comment: Yeah! That's understandable. The only difference is the post data I send. So, would it be a better idea to go with a single controller which will have different functions?

Comment: Nooooo! Why this fixation on doing everything in a single place? Have you ever seen an OO API where there is single class, and all the methods are in that single class? Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Oh! No... The reason is, I want to share the same scope value through out the application?

Comment: 1. there is no reason, at all, to have the same scope throughout the application. Having a separate scope per controller is a GOOD thing 2. All scopes directly or indirectly extend the root scope. 3. if you need to share data between controllers, that's what services, and your backend API, are for. Having a single scope is the equivalent of only having global variables in a language. Global variables are evil.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation I really appreciate your help. So, I have to look around some good references which will help me out with this. If I'm not wrong, What I understand from this discussion is that, the best thing to do is to have separate controllers for separate services and then controller call the respective services separately and then share the data based upon the requirement. Does it sound good?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angular application is totally separate from you back-end. It does not matter how the back-end is implemented.

You can create an Angular application without any back-end service whatsoever. This means you can use any type of routing in your front-end app.

The only part of your app which will be affected by your back-end design will be your services and how they get the data from your API.

Your routes, controllers and views do not (should not) care.

Comment: Thank you for giving me a detail information. One thing I'm concerned with is, So, is it advisable to keep same routes in my routing file for all the post methods? If yes how will my angular controller know to which route I have requested? I apologize if this questions sounds weired I'm new to angular JS!

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question, but I will try to explain the architecture. As far as the back-end goes, I would suggest you keep one controller per end-point. Whether your routes are defined in one file or somewhere close to the controller does not really matter. It usually depends on language, framework or preference.

Comment: When it comes to the front-end, some people keep they routes in one file and others keep one route per file. I would suggest the second approach, but I am sure there would be people suggesting otherwise, so use the one approach which is more natural to you (your team) and stick with it.

Comment: Routes of front-end and back-end are totally independent, so it does not matter how you structure either when it comes to routing. You can have both back-end and front-end dumped in one file (each) and live with it (obviously this is discouraged). Or you can chop them up as much as you like (within reason obviously).

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I would try to work on what you said. Basically, What I'm doing is I have a service which calls all the POST methods from the api. Then, I have one controller which calls all these methods in it and displays in the UI. The reason I had to go with this approach is, I had to share the data between these functions that's why I had to keep only one controller. So, Is it better idea to do so.  I really appreciate your advice. It helps!

Comment: That is definitely not the way. Split your application into logical components. Each component should focus on a specific thing. This way you can put your application together using small reusable components. These components can then be used on multiple pages, as they focus on one thing and thus, can be applied to do the same thing in different scenarios/pages.

Comment: So, can I share same scope values between the api methods,  if I have different controllers. I'm new to angular JS just started learning it. Can I have any reference or any examples which do the approach you mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you start with the official Angular tutorial. It is not in-depth, but great for beginners - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/. You will learn how to structure your Angular code there.

Comment: Okay! Sure I would do that. But this seems to be Angular 2. I would probably look for angular JS.

Comment: Angular2 is a newer version of the original AngularJS. If you are starting with angular or you are starting a new project, it makes sense to pick up Angular2. They are both very stable and with a great community. Take your pick.

Comment: Yes! I'm just starting up a new project. I feel like it is difficult to set up angular 2 in visual studio. I would go with Angular 1.x.x version.